# Common Lisp return associations from alist as new list

Tags: list, lisp, common-lisp, key-value-store

I have an assoc list as follows:

```
(defparameter *experts2*
  `(
    ;; direction
    (:direction . ( (nn-direction-expert (process-signal) :number-of-neighbors 10)
                    (fn-direction-expert (process-signal) :number-of-neighbors 10) ))



    ;; evaluation
    (:evaluation . ( 

                    ;(avoid-line-crossing-evaluation-expert (process-signal))
                    (nn-single-evaluation-expert (candidate-point))
                    (fn-single-evaluation-expert (candidate-point))
                    ;(nn-all-evaluation-expert (ranking))
                    ))

    ;; coordination
    (:coordination . (
                      ;(ranking-process (candidate-point))
                      (action-process (candidate-point ranking))))))
```

I am looking for a way, to extract the values from the key=>value list and put them into a new list like

```
(defparameter *experts*
  `(
    ;; direction
    (nn-direction-expert (process-signal) :number-of-neighbors 10)
    (fn-direction-expert (process-signal) :number-of-neighbors 10)

    ;eher als evaluationsexperte
    ;(avoid-line-crossing-evaluation-expert (process-signal) )

    ;; evaluation
    (nn-single-evaluation-expert (candidate-point))
    (fn-single-evaluation-expert (candidate-point))
    ;(nn-all-evaluation-expert (ranking))

    ;; coordination
    ;(ranking-process (candidate-point))
    (action-process (candidate-point ranking))
    ))
```

Any suggestions? Thanks for your help.

Regards

Answer (score 3):

This seems to produce the answer you want, but it doesn't seem very pretty:

```
(mapcan #'copy-list (mapcar #'cdr *experts2*))
```

Answer (score 0):

Samuel Edwin Ward's answer works, but here's another one (now edited to actually do what you need). So, you want to, for each element of the `*experts2*`, take its `cdr`, and then take the values from the returned lists and combine them into one list:

```
(apply #'append (mapcan #'cdr *experts2*))
```

Comment: This works, the first time.  I even tried it myself on the way to my answer.  But the perhaps insidious thing here is that it alters `*experts2*`.  This might be inconsistent with the request for "a new list".  This might be the best method to use in some circumstances, but it's definitely worth mentioning the drawbacks.

Comment: Ah, dang. I forgot that `mapcan` is destructive. I thought of a different way that I think is more straightforward than your answer, but isn't necessarily better.